# jQuery: Center text inside progress bar

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to center text vertically & horizontally inside jQuery progress bar. I managed center it horizontally but **not vertically**. [Here is what I have at the moment](http://jsfiddle.net/bLdgN/1/)

My `HTML`:

```
<div id='progressbar'><div id='label'>My text</div></div>
```

My `CSS`:

```
#progressbar {
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#label {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

My `JavaScript`:

```
$("#progressbar").progressbar({
    value: 50
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Managed by adding:

```
line-height: 200%;
```

The result: http://jsfiddle.net/GYW73/1/

My `HTML`:

```
<div id='progressbar'><div id='label'>My text</div></div>
```

My `CSS`:

```
#progressbar {
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
}

#label {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    line-height: 200%;
}
```

My `JavaScript`:

```
$("#progressbar").progressbar({
    value: 50
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a `line-height` to get it centered vertically:

```
line-height: 35px;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bLdgN/2/)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using hard-coded numbers? If I have to use magic numbers I would rather use 'margin-top' inside "#label"

Comment: @Caner - Actually there really isn't. You can set the line-height to a percentage, you can add margins, paddings or whatever, and then there's javascript and even CSS3 `calc()` that could probably be used in some way. Aligning something vertically with CSS has always been a lot more difficult than aligning something horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

The `vertical-align` style, when applied to block-level elements, seldom behaves the way you might expect it to.

The usage you've shown here works fine... with table cells. It acts like the old and deprecated HTML `valign` property. The behavior is different for inline elements, where it acts like the old and deprecated `align` HTML property.

When you apply it to box elements (like your div), the browser simply ignores it ([see the spec](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align))

Your options for vertical alignment in a block element are limited. You can either:

1) Use line-height to fill the entire vertical space. The browser will vertically align text within its line. The pro of this is that it doesn't require additional wrapping tags, the con is that you must work with a pre-defined height.

2) Use absolute positioning. The advantage of this approach is precision -- you can place the text **exactly** where you want it. Absolute positioning is pretty intuitive, too. The cons are that you'll need an additional wrapping tag, and you have to work with pre-defined heights.

The only saving grace you have is using percents. You can either use it in the `line-height` or as a `top`/`bottom` in combination with absolute position. Here is a mockup of your same code, using a percent `top` to push the div down into the center.

```
#label {
    width: 100%;
    top:2.5%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bLdgN/5/

**Documentation**

- `vertical-align` at W3 - http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align
- `vertical-align` at MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align
- *"Understanding vertical-align, or "How (Not) To Vertically Center Content""* at phrogz.net (accessed on 8/13) - http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/